# Defining a function to act upon an array

Tags: ruby

In Ruby, we define class member functions like this

```
class Dog
  def bark
    puts "woof"
  end
end
```

What I want to know and have been thoroughly unsuccessful in googling is, how and where does one define methods to act upon object-arrays in Ruby?

I wish to be able to do something like this:

```
dogs = [Dog.new, Dog.new, Dog.new]
dogs.some_function
```

How and where do I define `some_function`?

**Note:** I am not after solutions to a specific problem, more so the steps in how to define such a function in general.

Comment: What are you trying to do overall?

Comment: what should some_function do??

Comment: This is regardless of what I want to do, I just wanted to know if there is away to define methods on behalf of Arrays of a class in Ruby, I was unable to dig up specific information.

Comment: It could just have been making a function where `dogs.some_function` printed Meow. I just have been unable to make Ruby read `self` as an object array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make all your dogs bark, you should use `each` on the array:

```
dogs.each(&:bark)
```

which is equivalent to

```
dogs.each { |dog| dog.bark }
```

Very rarely you need to define a method *on* an array, in which case it will be available on all arrays, containing anything. To do that, you need to declare it *inside* the `Array` class, by declaring it again:

```
class Array
  def some_function
    # do something...
  end
end
```

And then you could run:

```
dogs = [Dog.new, Dog.new, Dog.new]
dogs.some_function
```

and also

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4]
numbers.some_function
```

Comment: Okay. Related followup-question: Where would I define Array-methods inside a Rails project?

Comment: The best place would be under `config/initializers`

Comment: Alright. I realize now that this is probably not what I will want to do, but your answer is correct nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

You could also create a class that inherits from `Array` such as

```
class DogWalker < Array
  def some_function
    self.each(&:bark)
  end
end

class Dog
  def bark
    puts "woof"
  end
end

d = DogWalker.new([Dog.new,Dog.new,Dog.new])
d.some_function 
#woof
#woof
#woof 
#=> [#<Dog:0x2a5a2e8>, #<Dog:0x2a5a2d0>, #<Dog:0x2a5a2b8>]
```

This means that you can only call this method on an instance of `DogWalker` (as well as all the methods available to `Array`) but does not alter `Array` itself. Giving you better control of the objects included in it. e.g.

```
class DogWalker < Array
  def initialize(args)
    raise ArgumentError.new("Must be an Array of Dogs") unless args.is_a?(Array) && args.all?{|e| e.is_a?(Dog)}
    super
  end
end

d = DogWalker.new([Dog.new,Dog.new,Dog.new])
#=>[#<Dog:0x2a5a2e8>, #<Dog:0x2a5a2d0>, #<Dog:0x2a5a2b8>]
d = DogWaler.new([Dog.new,12])
#=>ArgumentError: Must be an Array of Dogs
Array.new([1,2,3])
#=>[1,2,3]
```

As @UriAgassi pointed out very rarely do you need to alter base classes especially if you are designing extended functionality that does not need to/cannot apply across object types. Here is an example:

```
class Array
  def some_function
    self.map(&:bark)
  end
end
class Dog
  def bark
    "woof"
  end
end
d = [Dog.new,Dog.new]
d.some_function
#=> ["woof","woof"]
d = [1,2,3,4]
d.some_function
#=>NoMethodError: undefined method `bark' for 1:Fixnum
```

Since `Array` can accept any object type the `Array` is fine but the `some_function` method requires an object that `responds_to` `bark` which will raise in the event the object cannot perform the task requested.

Answer (score 0):

In your example 'dogs' is the instance of [Array class](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html). 
If you want to extend Array class you can add method to it like this:

```
class Array
  def some_function
  end
end
```